# My question is regarding Periodic Table, Why there are three columns for 8B group in old version of the periodic table?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why there are three separate columns for 8B group in old version of the periodic table?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! What efforts have you made to get the answer to your question? Effort is the imaginary currency you use in chem SE to gain answers.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal I like that, it's both concise and accurate :-)

Comment: @SyedFaisal. You are looking at an old version of the periodic table. Please forget about it. Please consider the periodic table with 18 columns, and not with 8 columns,